# why do I get negative angle as output when using np.degrees(np.math.atan2(np.linalg.det([A,B]),np.dot(A,B)))?

Tags: python, numpy

I am calculating the angle between two vectors AB and CB where

```
a = np.array(x0,y0)
b = np.array([xi,yi])
c = np.array([x1,y1])
AB = a-b
CB = c-b
```

when converting the angle to degrees using `np.degrees(np.math.atan2(np.linalg.det([AB,CB]),np.dot(AB,CB)))` I see negative values for some degree angles.
can someone please explain why?

Comment: Its because `atan2` return negative Radian value and when `np.degrees` get negative Radian it return a negative degree

Comment: @ David S, does the negative sign of the radian value imply a clockwise measured angle?

Answer (score 0):

`ata2`returns the signed angle, thus in the upper quadrants you will have a positive values and in the lower quadrants negative values.

For comparison see [wiki atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: Hi @maxkno and welcome to StackOverflow. please edit the answer to report `atan2`